# Noob needs assistance with linking javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

I need to link up my javascript with my HTML, however I cannot properly do this.  I created my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs     /jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        </head>
        <body>

            <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

            <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

            <button id="button1">Grow</button>
            <button id="button2">Blue</button>
            <button id="button3">Fade</button>
            <button id="button4">Reset</button>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>    

    </body>
</html>
```

I basically need to create a simple site with four buttons which are interactive.  I also created a file called javascript.js in the same folder as my index.html.  I believe the script to make the button grow is:

```
document.getElementById("growBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";
});
```

May someone please tell me how I can make this work?

A:  Did I link this properly to point to the JavaScript file?

B:  Is the code correct to make the button work?

Thank you for any assistance. I am at the infancy stage of coding.

Comment: For both A and B, only you can answer: does it work? Just try it and see (if not, what doesn't work?) If it does work, then you did it right. (do you have a `#growBtn` anywhere?)

Comment: Cheers and welcome to SO. To check if your script is correctly loaded just open a console (f12) and check the "net" tab (in most browsers is called like that anyway). Or just add an alert or console log at the beginning of the script. We cannot answer more than it "looks" fine because we have no idea what your config is. Maybe you have a htaccess redirect for all things that start with "j" for all we know :). The event itself is fine (with the addition Jack Bashford has in his answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code will work, ***if*** you add the event listener to the correct element. Currently you're looking for an element `id="growBtn"` which doesn't exist in your HTML - call the function instead on `id="button1"`:

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){

    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";

});
```

Comment: Awesome!  Got it.  One other question.  How can I get button 3 to fade?

Comment: Can you use jQuery? If so, use the `.fadeToggle()` method

Comment: I got it to fade by adding this: `document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function(){
    box.style.opacity = 0.5; 
 });`